# Compile Sencha EXT JS theme with SASS mapping for Chrome Canary

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, sass

Chrome Canary offers some excellent SASS inspector features IF you can compile your theme with debug information. I've figure out how to do this in generic Compass styles sheets with the line:`sass_options = { :debug_info=>true }`, however EXT JS has build process that (no matter what it seems) always compiles the SASS files compressed. Their "testing" command can expand this file, but I still need the @media tags (or the debug info) in order to get SASS inspector to work.

Does anyone know how to alter the Sencha EXT JS theme build process to add in debug info for Canary support? Or does anyone know what `build.css.preprocessor.opts.production` does in build.properties as it may be related?

Comment: You may find this background information useful: http://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps

Answer (score 1):

So I have this working now, it's not as great as I'd like it to be since Ext-JS has a TON of mixins and other imports. However here is how to get it working.

System Setup (versions here are important as Chrome 27+ only supports a certain type of source mapping):
`Ext-JS 4.2.1`
`SASS (3.3.0.alpha.149)`
`Compass (0.12.2)`

After that is established, go to your theme package and run `sencha package build`. This, more or less, builds a /build folder in your themes package. This build will also generate a `{theme-name}-all.scss` which grabs all other mixins and includes needed to be compiled independently, this is crucial!

Once that is done, you can run something like this:
`sass --compass --sourcemap {theme-name}-all.scss:resources/{theme-name}-all.css`

Obviously change these to suit your environment. What this will do is build a compiled css file in the /resources directory (which should be there), and it's important to compile there as all your images and other resources relatively linked to your stylesheet.

From there I changed the index.html (should be in the root of your app) to point to this newly generated css file. Chrome also needs to be setup to use this information, however that's outside of this question.

Hope this helps someone else out there. It really is a mixed bag as the theming involved in Sencha has a lot going on. Hopefully this'll get better over time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch the mode by:

```
sencha package build development // or `build debug`
```

As for the `build.css.preprocessor.opts.production`, definitely it can be used (check [sencha test](https://github.com/sencha/SenchaTestDemo/blob/master/AdminDashboard/.sencha/app/defaults.properties)):

```
build.options=logger:${build.options.logger},
debug:${build.options.debug},
product:${build.options.product},
minVersion:${build.options.minVersion},
${build.options.default},
${build.options.custom}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are looking for free sencha themes or sencha theme builder here is a great site for that

http://developerextensions.com/index.php/sencha-theme-builder